# Unable to access Minio console on my private server

Tags: docker, server, dns, minio, caddy

I am unable to access Minio console on my private server, I intend to run two containers of Minio.

`docker-compose.yaml`

```bash
version: '3.8'

services:
  minio_server_one:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: minio_server_one
    volumes:
      - ./minio/data:/data
    expose:
      - 9000
      - 9091
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER_ONE}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD_ONE}
      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: http://stash-one.localhost
    command: "server /data --console-address ':9090'"

  minio_server_two:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: minio_server_two
    volumes:
      - ./minio/data:/data
    expose:
      - 9001
      - 9092
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER_TWO}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD_TWO}
      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: http://stash-two.localhost
    command: "server /data --console-address ':9093'"  

  caddy_reverse_proxy:
      container_name: caddy_reverse_proxy
      image: caddy:alpine
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 80:80      
        - 443:443
      environment:
        - EXT_ENDPOINT1=${EXT_ENDPOINT1}
        - LOCAL_1=${LOCAL_1}
        - LOCAL_2=${LOCAL_2}
      volumes:
        - ./caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
        - ./static:/code/static
        - caddy_data:/data
        - caddy_config:/config

volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

I am using `Caddy` as well.

`Caddyfile`

`{$EXT_ENDPOINT1}` should refer to `mybeautifuldomain.com`.

```bash
storage-one.{$EXT_ENDPOINT1}, storage-one.{$LOCAL_1}, storage-one.{$LOCAL_2} {
  reverse_proxy minio_server_one:9000 
}

stash-one.{$EXT_ENDPOINT1}, stash-one.{$LOCAL_1}, stash-one.{$LOCAL_2} {
  reverse_proxy minio_server_one:9090 
}

storage-two.{$EXT_ENDPOINT1}, storage-two.{$LOCAL_1}, storage-two.{$LOCAL_2} {
  reverse_proxy minio_server_two:9001 
}

stash-two.{$EXT_ENDPOINT1}, stash-two.{$LOCAL_1}, stash-two.{$LOCAL_2} {
  reverse_proxy minio_server_two:9093 
}
```

`.env`

```bash
#############################################
# Caddy variables
#############################################
EXT_ENDPOINT1=mybeautifuldomain.com
LOCAL_1=localhost
LOCAL_2=127.0.0.1

#############################################
# Minio variables
#############################################
MINIO_URL_ONE=storage-one.localhost
MINIO_BUCKET_ONE=minio-one
MINIO_ROOT_USER_ONE=minioadmin
MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD_ONE=SECRETSECRET

#############################################
# Minio variables
#############################################
MINIO_URL_TWO=storage-two.localhost
MINIO_BUCKET_TWO=minio-two
MINIO_ROOT_USER_TWO=minioadmin
MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD_TWO=SECRETSECRET
```

When I tested it locally by running `docker compose up`, I can access the console on both `stash-one.localhost` and `stash-two.localhost`.

I have also, via GoDaddy, set up my DNS Record as such, for `stash-one`, `stash-two`, `storage-one` and `storage-two`, like so:

[image]

Even then, I am still unable to access the console on my website, say, `mybeautifuldomain.com`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own issue with the following modifications to the `docker-compose.yaml` and `Caddyfile` as follows:

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  minio_server_one:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: minio_server_one
    volumes:
      - ./minio/data-one:/data # ensuring container is mirroring a different volume
    expose:
      - 9000 # ensuring it is not used by `minio_server_two`
      - 9091 # ensuring it is not used by `minio_server_two`
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER_ONE}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD_ONE}
      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: http://stash-one.${EXT_ENDPOINT1}
    # the most important change is HERE
    # instead of http://stash-one.localhost
    # change this to http://stash-one.${EXT_ENDPOINT1}
    # note the domain prefix is unique as well
    command: "server /data --console-address ':9090'"
    # make sure the ':9090' ports are unique for minio_server_one and two

  minio_server_two:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: minio_server_two
    volumes:
      - ./minio/data-two:/data # ensuring container is mirroring a different volume
    expose:
      - 9001 # ensuring it is not used by `minio_server_one`
      - 9092 # ensuring it is not used by `minio_server_one`
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER_TWO}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD_TWO}
      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: http://stash-two.${EXT_ENDPOINT1}
    command: "server /data --console-address ':9093'"  

  caddy_reverse_proxy:
      container_name: caddy_reverse_proxy
      image: caddy:alpine
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 80:80      
        - 443:443
      environment:
        - EXT_ENDPOINT1=${EXT_ENDPOINT1}
        - LOCAL_1=${LOCAL_1}
        - LOCAL_2=${LOCAL_2}
      volumes:
        - ./caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
        - ./static:/code/static
        - caddy_data:/data
        - caddy_config:/config

volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

`Caddyfile`

```
storage-one.{$EXT_ENDPOINT1}, storage-one.{$LOCAL_1}, storage-one.{$LOCAL_2} {
  reverse_proxy minio_server_one:9000
  # state exactly the name of the container `minio_server_one`
  # the port should be the first exposed port in `docker-compose.yaml`
}

stash-one.{$EXT_ENDPOINT1}, stash-one.{$LOCAL_1}, stash-one.{$LOCAL_2} {
  reverse_proxy minio_server_one:9090
  # the `stash-one` prefix should point to the port declared in the
  # command segment of the `docker-compose.yaml` file
  # e.g. command: "server /data --console-address ':9090'"
  #                                                ^^^^^
}

storage-two.{$EXT_ENDPOINT1}, storage-two.{$LOCAL_1}, storage-two.{$LOCAL_2} {
  reverse_proxy minio_server_two:9001 
}

stash-two.{$EXT_ENDPOINT1}, stash-two.{$LOCAL_1}, stash-two.{$LOCAL_2} {
  reverse_proxy minio_server_two:9093 
}
```